# How do I configure localStorage for enabling dark mode?

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I have a bare bones Astro project where I am using vanilla HTML, CSS, and JS. I am trying to enable the ability to toggle dark mode. I have a global.css file with root styles:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

:root {
  --primary: white;
  --text: black;
}

.darkmode {
  --primary: black;
  --text: white;
}
```

I then have a button component:

```
<button class="darkmode-toggle" aria-pressed="false">Enable Dark Mode</button>

<script>
  let darkmode = localStorage.getItem('darkmode');
  const systemPrefs = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;
  const darkmodeToggle = document.querySelector('.darkmode-toggle');

  const enableDarkmode = () => {
    document.documentElement.classList.add('darkmode');
    darkmodeToggle.textContent = 'Disable Dark Mode';
    darkmodeToggle.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'true');

    localStorage.setItem('darkmode', 'enabled')
  }

  const disableDarkmode = () => {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove('darkmode')
    darkmodeToggle.textContent = 'Enable Dark Mode'
    darkmodeToggle.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'false')

    localStorage.setItem('darkmode', null)
  }

  if (darkmode === 'enabled' || systemPrefs) enableDarkmode()

  darkmodeToggle.addEventListener('click', _ => {
    darkmode = localStorage.getItem('darkmode')

    darkmode !== 'enabled'
      ? enableDarkmode()
      : disableDarkmode()
  })
</script>
```

This implementation works which you will be able to see from [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-field-8k3sle?file=/src/components/DarkMode.astro:0-1099) CodeSandbox. This issue I'm having is that when the page refreshes, the color goes back to the default.

I'm assuming this is usually fixed by using localStorage, which I am, making me think there's something off about my implementation. Where am I misusing localStorage?

Comment: see my anwser here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68868558/toggle-one-button-toggle-the-other-one-as-well/68877452#68877452  'second part use localeStorage and browser dark mode setting

Comment: Wow! It is working as expected which is great. I will have to take some time to digest it :) thank you for that thorough answer, I upvoted!