# How do I implement the saving of dark/light mode feature to local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Note that, the website is hosted on a PC. I have tried various methods which didn't work. View my codes added below. Everything works as it should except that the mode returns to light mode upon refresh of my browser even when the toggle is set to dark mode. Also, note that I have no previous experience with the use of local storage. What's the best solution that applies to my codes?

```html
<header>
  <div class="controls">
    <p>Light/Dark Mode</p>
    <label class="toggle-switch" for="dark-mode-toggle">
      <input type="checkbox" id="dark-mode-toggle" name="theme" onclick="otherColorChanges()" onreset="restoreDefaultColor()">
      <div class="toggle-switch-border">
        <div class="toggle-switch-dot"></div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</header>
```

```css
.toggle-switch {
  display     : inline-flex;
  align-items : center;
  font-family : 'Sora', sans-serif;
  font-weight : 700;
  font-size   : .875rem;
  cursor      : pointer;
  }
.toggle-switch-border {
  display             : inline-flex;
  align-items         : center;
  width               : 60px;
  height              : 36px;
  border              : 1px solid var(--primary); 
  border-radius       : 20px;
  box-sizing          : border-box;
  margin-inline-start : 8px;
  }
.toggle-switch input {
  display: none;
  }
.toggle-switch-dot {
  width         : 28px;
  height        : 28px;
  border-radius : 50%;
  background    : var(--primary);
  transform     : translate3d(3px, 0, 0);
  transition    : transform .1s ease-in-out;
  }
.toggle-switch input:checked + * .toggle-switch-dot {
  transform : translate3d(26px, 0, 0);
  }
body {
  color              : var(--primary);
  font-family        : "Work Sans", sans-serif;
  background         : var(--background);
  /*box-sizing       : border-box;*/
  transition         : color 0.5s;
  transition         : background 0.5s;
 
  --dark-background  : #253a52;
  --dark-primary     : white; /*#FFFFE3*/
  --dark-link        : #A9FE75;
 
  --light-background : white; /*#ffffe3*/
  --light-primary    : #253a52;
  --light-link       : #1348da;
 
  --background       : var(--light-background);
  --primary          : var(--light-primary);
  --link             : var(--light-link);
  }
a {
  color : var(--link);
  }
/* separator bars */
nav,
section {
  border-block-end : 1px solid var(--primary);
  }
/* container for dark-mode toggle */
header .controls {
  display         : flex;
  justify-content : end;
  padding         : 1rem 0;
  margin-right    : 3rem;
  }
 a.btn {
  display         : inline-flex;
  align-items     : center;
  background      : var(--link);
  color           : var(--background);
  text-decoration : none;
  padding         : 0 1rem;
  height          : 2.5rem;
  border-radius   : 1.25rem;
  font-family     : "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight     : 700;
  font-size       : 0.875rem;
  }
```

```
/*Light/Dark mode toggle*/
class CssPropControl {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element
  }
  get(varName) {
    return getComputedStyle(this.element).getPropertyValue(varName)
  }
  set(varName, val) {
    return this.element.style.setProperty(varName, val)
  }
}

const bodyCssProps = new CssPropControl(document.body)

let toggle = document.querySelector('#dark-mode-toggle')
toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let mode = toggle.checked ? 'dark' : 'light'
  bodyCssProps.set('--background', bodyCssProps.get(`--${mode}-background`))
  bodyCssProps.set('--primary', bodyCssProps.get(`--${mode}-primary`))
  bodyCssProps.set('--link', bodyCssProps.get(`--${mode}-link`))
})


/*Save dark mode in local storage*/
const darkModeToggle = document.getElementById('darkModeToggle');

darkModeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  darkModeToggle.checked ? document.body.classList.add("bodyCssProps") : document.body.classList.remove("bodyCssProps");
  localStorage.setItem('darkModeStatus', darkModeToggle.checked);
});

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('darkModeStatus') == "true") {
    document.body.classList.add("bodyCssProps");
    document.getElementById('darkModeToggle').checked = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68868558/toggle-one-button-toggle-the-other-one-as-well/68877452#68877452

Comment: I have tried implementation found via the link but the page keeps returning to the default light mode upon refresh. What's the solution for my code?

Comment: Yes, I used the full JS code (with window.matchMedia and localStorage ): part

Comment: There are mistakes in your code.

Comment: It's weird, I just re-tested this code just now and it works wonderfully. I do not see how to help you otherwise, because I do not debug code, and I doubt that the purpose of this site goes in this direction.

Comment: witch `mistakes` do you get ?

Comment: What mistakes are in the code? As I explained earlier I have no prior experience with local storage. Can I see your code that allows the page to remain in dark mode upon refresh?

Comment: getElementById('darkModeToggle') when the id is "dark-mode-toggle".  I changed that and it remembered the theme between reloads.

Comment: I changed the id to darkModeToggle but it marks the dark mode stop working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71032440/2813224

Comment: `Can I see your code that allows the page to remain in dark mode upon refresh?` this is on this line :   `darkMode = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem(darkClass) || darkMode.toString() )`

Comment: The implementation is not working with my code. Can I see the functional implementation with my code so I can study it?

Comment: You can see your code working in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nmzxyw12/).  There were multiple problems.  The dark-mode-toggle id needed to be changed in 2 places. That fixes the toggle button.  Yet, to make it actually flip mode on load you need to set the css variables during load.  You also need to remove the onclick=otherColorChanges because that function doesn't exist.

Comment: The JSFiddle contains the functional implementation with my code. Very insightful and useful for study purposes. Thanks, I'll accept it if you decide to post it as a code here.

Comment: Great, that's good to know.  Yet, please consider accepting @Levidps answer as I don't mind.

Comment: @Yogi See a follow-up question to this here, your input is needed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74779679/how-do-i-fix-dark-mode-not-retaining-across-multiple-html-pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your event listeners and how your css variables are being updated. I'm guessing your local storage is correctly getting accessed and your checkbox is properly set on load, however your variables are only updated when `onClick` is fired.

You have two options:

1. modify your code so that there's a way to trigger css variable updates without using `onClick`
2. directly call `darkModeToggle.onClick()` after setting the checkbox value to get it to call your css variable update

Comment: The onClick currently performs no function. It's a remnant of a previous attempt

Comment: @ZeroHour perhaps it’s worth cleaning up your code. If you’ve made modifications or posted dead code it makes it harder for people to assist with resolving your issue…

Comment: Up vote.  The code has multiple problems that need to be fixed, but this answer points out one of the significant ones, i.e., update css variables during load.

Comment: @Levidps See a follow-up question to this here, your input is needed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74779679/how-do-i-fix-dark-mode-not-retaining-across-multiple-html-pages