# how to Change dark theme to light teme after reclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes, dark-theme

i made  a button that when u click it,  the webpage turn to dark theme but when i reclick it, it stays black i want it to return back to the default (white) like a loop

```
const myBtn = document.getElementById("darktheme");
const body = document.body;
const welcome = document.getElementById("txtt")

myBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(17, 17, 17)";
    body.style.color = "white";
    welcome.style.color = "white";
    
})
```

can anyone Help ?

Comment: have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68868558/toggle-one-button-toggle-the-other-one-as-well/68877452#68877452

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Base on your code :

```js
const myBtn = document.getElementById("darktheme");
const body = document.body;
const welcome = document.getElementById("txtt");

myBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(body.style.backgroundColor==="rgb(17, 17, 17)")
    {
      body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(256, 256, 256)";
      body.style.color = "black";
      welcome.style.color = "black";
    }
    else
    {
      body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(17, 17, 17)";
      body.style.color = "white";
      welcome.style.color = "black";
    }
})
```

```html
<button id="darktheme">darktheme</button>
<input type="text" id="txtt"/>
```

Comment: The button doesn't activate the dark theme anymore. Same happens when I try copying and pasting the code ChatGpt gave me, the dark theme still doesn't work. What should I share with you to help me find the issue?

Comment: Why? Just copy my code in your HTML file, you can see my code result by press (Run code snippet)

Comment: ight thanks bro it seems like i had problem in my html code

Answer (score 1):

Don't manipulate styles manually. Just toggle a class for `body` and write appropriate styles for this class:

```css
body.darktheme{
  color:white;
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.body.classList.toggle('darktheme')">Toggle dark theme</button>

<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

Comment: My JavaScript code makes the button change to a black theme. However, I want it to switch back to white when I click it again, and then return to black when I click it once more, creating a looping effect.

Comment: @Ayman my code does exactly that, what's the problem?

Comment: When I applied what you showed me to my website, the dark theme didn't work at all, just like every code ChatGPT gave me. What do you suggest I share with you from my code to help identify the problem?

Comment: @Ayman in that case you really need to amend how your CSS is structured to use the single class on the `body` to toggle the dark mode. While the answers below may work, they are leading you down a path which will give you a ***massive*** maintenance headache when you come to make any changes to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Just make use of `toggle` classList and then use CSS to add your styles.

```js
const myBtn = document.getElementById("toggle-theme");
const body = document.body;
const welcome = document.getElementById("txtt")

myBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
   body.classList.toggle('dark')
    
})
```

```css
body { background-color: white; color: black;}
body #txtt { color: black; }
body.dark { background-color:black; color: white}
body.dark #txtt { color: white }
```

```html
<button id="toggle-theme">toggle</button>
<div id="txtt">Welcome</div>
```